# Adding posts to a custom blog?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, blogs

I'm setting up a custom blog that grabs the posts from a mysql database. Everything is working great, but what I'm wondering is how I should go about adding posts to the database. I can only think of creating a random page that needs password access with a textarea and submit button, or just adding it in PHPMyAdmin. Neither of those two methods seems very practical, though.

How does Jeff Atwood himself do it? How should I do it?

edit: For clarification, this is not a blog system, this is a website I'm working on for myself.

Comment: Your reputation makes me wonder if this is real?

Comment: Still wanting the answer if anyone cares to give it...

Comment: Simple login system? This sounds like a job for [Superman](https://browserid.org/)!

Comment: @Xeoncross, Not looking for a login system, I just want to know the best way to upload blog posts to a MySql database.

Comment: @Walkerneo, but you will need some kind of password-protected login to prevent unauthorized access. So you can either build a full user system - or just use browserID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly instead of a textarea I would use [CK editor](http://ckeditor.com/) (or your favourite replacement) unless you're happy to enter the HTML yourself.  Since you're the only person using the site this is probably the case.

Securing the form can be very simple or very elaborate.  As you say it's just for yourself and not for anybody else I would suggest putting it into a folder (not named admin) and using .htaccess as basic user authentication.  This is really easy and fast to set up.  Here's the top [Google Result for online tools](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/).

The reason I'm suggesting this solution is that it will take only a few minutes to set up.  It's not 100% secure, but otherwise you would need coding effort to create signon pages and session handling etc.  I guess you could even have a password field on the input form itself and check this in your processing logic.  Sort of like a failback on the .htaccess that would prevent action from being taken on submitted forms unless the correct password is entered.  Somebody could penetrate .htaccess and view the form, but not use it.

I'm pretty sure the major bloggers have got admin backends that they login to in order to be able to post.  Almost certainly they have access control levels to assign roles to specific users.  All of this is probably overkill for a simple site where this feature is not the main function of the site but rather a side attraction.

If it is a big part of the site you could do an installation of an existing CMS (Wordpress,Joomla, Drupal) in a subdirectory and then get your content feeder to pull from the CMS database.  That's a pretty big footprint but then at least you'll have all the features of the CMS at your disposal.  It's also pretty impractical and seems wasteful to have an entire CMS to provide snippets.

What specifically is not practical about a form?  Are you thinking more along the lines of polling an RSS feed for content?  If you're wanting your own content to appear you're going to have to enter it *somewhere*.  I can't think of a way to do it more easily than with a form.

Comment: Awesome, exactly the response I was looking for. What's the insecurity about the .htaccess file password though? I was considering it, but did have the creeping suspicion that it wasn't fool-proof.

Answer (score 1):

I would look up sessions for PHP.
This way you can have a table in you database called users and have a username or eamil and password. When someone tried to log in you compare that to your users table and then you set your sessions so they dont have to log in with every page refresh. Next step is easy like you said just have a form that posts to your database.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should research sessions and cookies. These things can be used as a form of authentication. You make a loginpage and when the user is authenticated you save a key in the session or cookie. But you need to watch out, because there could be security leaks when you don't program it well.